# C# async/await await doesn't await

Tags: c#, async-await

I am using .Net 4.7.2 and C# 7

In a class there are serveral methods, all void. Some of them can be executed asynchronously, others have to be executed sequentially. So I defined a list for the parallels

```
private void ExecuteSequential()
{
    SomeMethod1();
    SomeMethod2();
    ExecuteParallelAsync();
    SomeMethod3();
    SomeMethod4();
}


private async void ExecuteParallelAsync()
{
    List<Action> methods = new List<Action>()
    {
        MyMethod1,
        MyMethod2,
        MyMethod3
    };


    await Task.Run( () => { Parallel.ForEach( methods , ( currentMethod ) => currentMethod.Invoke() ); } );            
}
```

Before *SomeMethod3* happens to be executed *ExecuteParallelAsync* should be finished entirely.
Because that's not the case, apparently something is wrong with my usage of async and await.

What I am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`async void` - all bets are off; in reality, you should **never** write an `async void` method unless you're in the *tiny tiny* set of extreme corner cases that require it, such as async event-handlers.

> Before SomeMethod3 happens to be executed ExecuteParallelAsync should be finished entirely.

***how could it possibly know?*** it is: `async void`, which means it *doesn't give anything to the caller that indicates the state*.

To *do that*, it *must* be:

```cs
private async Task ExecuteParallelAsync() // or ValueTask
```

and you **must** await it **at the call site**

```cs
await ExecuteParallelAsync();
```

Comment: Thank you very much Marc. That solved the problem indeed. But, I'd like to add something. To be able to use *await ExecuteParallelAsync();* you also have to set *ExecuteSequential* from *void* to *async Task*

Comment: @GeorgeDuke the key point is adding the `async`, but yes: it would be a good idea to make it `async Task`, not `async void` - for all the same reasons

Answer (score 4):

Marc's answer is the correct solution, but I wanted to explain more about why.

A very key thing to understand about `async` methods is that:

1. They start synchronously.
2. When the `await` keyword is used, and `await` given an incomplete `Task`, *the method returns* - yes, even if you're only halfway through your method. The magic is in *what* it returns.

So lets look at what your code does:

1. Call `ExecuteParallelAsync()`.
2. `ExecuteParallelAsync()` starts running synchronously.
3. `Task.Run` returns a `Task` object that is not complete yet.
4. The `await` keyword inspects the `Task`, sees that it is not complete, so it creates a new `Task`, signs up the rest of the method as a continuation of that `Task` (there is nothing left to do in this case, but it still happens) *and returns*.
5. Because the return type is `void` it cannot return a `Task`. But it still returns!

So all that means that `ExecuteParallelAsync()` returns before the `Task.Run` is completed, and `ExecuteSequential()` has no way to tell when the work is actually complete.

This is commonly called "fire and forget" (i.e. "go do this and I don't care when or if you finish").

As Marc's answer points out, if you want to know when it's done, you need to return a `Task`, which you can then `await` to know when it's done.

Microsoft has very well written articles about asynchronous programming that you may benefit from reading: [Asynchronous programming with async and await](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/)

Comment: Thank you very much Gabriel, as you can imagine, I'm new to the topic, so I appreciate your effort and the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

If you want an implementation without async/await sugar keyword:

```cs
private void ExecuteParallelAsync()
{
    List<Action> methods = new List<Action>()
    {
        MyMethod1,
        MyMethod2,
        MyMethod3
    };

    Task.WaitAll(methods.Select((action) => Task.Run(action)).ToArray())   
}
```

Comment: Just be aware that `Task.WaitAll` blocks the current thread (it is not asynchronous).

Comment: it's a good remark. MyMethod1, MyMethod2, MyMethod3 will be executed in parallel between SomeMethod2() and SomeMethod3()

Comment: Thanks Tohm, but unfortunately, the results are the same compared to my incorrect implementation. At least in my case.

Comment: Have you deleted 'async' before ExecuteParallelAsync ?  MyMethod1, MyMethod2, MyMethod3 are synchronous functions ?

Comment: Yes, I did. Like you said I tested *void ExecuteParallelAsync* (I know, the naming is wrong in this particular case). And yes, none of the methods which are called by *ExecuteParallelAsync* is written asynchronously. The signature is always *void Something* no async, no Task.

Answer (score 0):

## Step 1, reproduce

```
public void Method()
    {
        SomeMethod();
        SomeMethod();
        ExecuteParallelAsync(); //< ---fire and forget 
        SomeMethod();
        SomeMethod();
        
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private void SomeMethod() => Console.WriteLine($"SomeMethod");
    
    private async void ExecuteParallelAsync()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"START");
        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100));
        Console.WriteLine($"END");
    }
```

Output

```
SomeMethod
SomeMethod
START
SomeMethod
SomeMethod
END
```

## Step 2, trying to fix

"Oh yes, I forgot to await my function"

```
await ExecuteParallelAsync(); //Change 1. "I forgot to await"
```

Output

```
Compilation error (line 12, col 3): The 'await' operator can only be used within an async method. Consider marking this method with the 'async' modifier and changing its return type to 'Task'.
Compilation error (line 12, col 3): Cannot await 'void'
```

## Step 3, fix

Addressing both errors from step 2.

```
// Change 2
// was:public void Main()  
// which caused: "The 'await' operator can only (...)"
public async Task Main() 
(...)
// Change 3
// was: private async void ExecuteParallelAsync()
// which caused "Compilation error (line 12, col 3): Cannot await 'void'"
private async Task ExecuteParallelAsync()
```

Run.

Output:

```
SomeMethod
SomeMethod
START
END
SomeMethod
SomeMethod
```

For reference, we could have waited for `ExecuteParallelAsync` without the `await` keyword, but `await` is the correct way in all scenarios except the *tiny* minority where it's not.

Comment: Thanks tymtam, but I can't use a static method, because I need the object, meaning the currently used instance of the class.

Comment: static is not important here. Gimme a sec, I'll update the code.

Comment: Thanks again, but Marc and Gabriel pointed out that *async void* should never be used. Do you disagree?

Comment: I don't disagree, my answer shows why it shouldn't be used.

Answer (score 0):

***a small complete example:***

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SomeMethod1();
            ExecuteParallelAsync();
            SomeMethod2();
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        static void SomeMethod1()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("SomeMethod1");
        }
        static void SomeMethod2()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("SomeMethod2");
        }

        static void ExecuteParallelAsync()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\tstart of ExecuteParallelAsync");
            var rd = new Random();

            List<Action> methods = new List<Action>()
            {
                ()=>{Thread.Sleep((int) Math.Ceiling(rd.NextDouble()*1000));Console.WriteLine("MyMethod1"); },
                ()=>{Thread.Sleep((int) Math.Ceiling(rd.NextDouble()*1000));Console.WriteLine("MyMethod2"); },
                ()=>{Thread.Sleep((int) Math.Ceiling(rd.NextDouble()*1000));Console.WriteLine("MyMethod3"); },
            };
            Task.WaitAll(methods.Select((action) => Task.Run(action)).ToArray());

            Console.WriteLine("\tend of ExecuteParallelAsync");
        }

    }
}
```

***example of a result:***

```
SomeMethod1
        start of ExecuteParallelAsync
MyMethod2
MyMethod3
MyMethod1
        end of ExecuteParallelAsync
SomeMethod2
```