# Extending C# async/await await doesn't await

Tags: c#, async-await

Extending: [C# async/await await doesn't await](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58431968/c-sharp-async-await-await-doesnt-await)

In case the methods executed sequentially are stored in a list as well, how can I add the *ExecuteParallelAsync* to that list?

```
private async Task ExecuteSequential()
{
    List<Action> sequentialMethods = new List<Action>()
    {
        SomeMethod1,
        SomeMethod2,
        await ExecuteParallelAsync, // ???
        SomeMethod3,
        SomeMethod4
    };

    for ( int i = 0 ; i < sequentialMethods.Count ; i++ )
    {
        sequentialMethods.ElementAt( i ).Invoke();
    }
}
```

**Clarification:**

```
private async Task ExecuteParallelAsync()
{
    List<Action> methods = new List<Action>()
    {
        MyMethod1,
        MyMethod2,
        MyMethod3
    };


    await Task.Run( () => { Parallel.ForEach( methods , ( currentMethod ) => currentMethod.Invoke() ); } );            
}
```

*sequentialMethods* is a **List<*Action*>** but *ExecuteParallelAsync* is NOT an Action. I've tried to split the list, like suggested. Unfortunately, it doesn't help.

The way suggested by Marc from the original code works fine. But I want to do some extra stuff after each (sequential) method call, which is why I'm trying to use a list and a loop instead of plain method calls.

But when I do so, I'm facing the original problem again, that SomeMethod3 is executed before ExecuteParallelAsync is finished.

Once again, everything in *ExecuteParallelAsync* can and should be executed simultaneously. Everything in *ExecuteSequential* has to be executed sequentially.

**Solution:**

Gabriel is absolutely correct. The crucial statement is this

```
await Task.Run( () => { Parallel.ForEach( methods , ( currentMethod ) => currentMethod.Invoke() ); } );
```

When I remove every async and every Task, so that everything is intended to run be executed sequentially this line is the key:

```
Parallel.ForEach( methods , ( currentMethod ) => currentMethod.Invoke() );
```

When I use this last statement, everything works correctly.

Thanks to everyone, all your ideas, thoughts and efforts helped and are appreciated.

Comment: Await is syntactic sugar to cut the method into a statemachine. How would it cut a list in muliple methods? The await should be done when calling a method and cannot be generated dynamically. This is done at compile time.

Comment: Split it into two lists and loops. Run those before. The await. Then those after.

Comment: In my experience, `ParallelFor` doesn't play well with async functions.

Comment: @Theodor Zoulias No, I don't insist on keeping *async void*. I did copy/paste from the original code and missed correcting the signature. But I'm going to take care of that right now. The real code statement is already changed to *async Task*. But, the problem remains the same.

Comment: @Neil What would be a better approach?

Comment: This also depends on how `MyMethod1`/`MyMethod2`/`MyMethod3` are implemented. Are they `async` methods?

Comment: No, they aren't. They are plain protected virtual void in the base class and therefore protected override void in the derived class. The only two methods that I have changed are ExecuteSequential and ExecuteParallelAsync from (async) void to async Task.

Comment: If they're not async, you can't await them. Your creating a task, to await it, then creating other tasks to run non-async code. Why? This is just making your code less efficient for no benefit. Just use a parallel for <full stop> (which is basically what [Gabirel has said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58452966/542251))

Comment: The solution you found makes no sense to me. The `Task.Run()` shouldn't change the flow of the program, since it is awaited. It does has an effect (the current thread is not involved in the execution of the parallel work), but shouldn't have the effect you describe. I am pretty sure that you made other changes as well, and some of these was the crucial, that eliminated a fire-and-forget task from the flow of your program.

Comment: I removed **every** *async* and every *await* and every *Task.Run* and of course I changed the Parallel statement like shown in the original post. Nothing else, and nothing else did I describe in the solution. Just to be sure, that the parallel execution is really simultaneously I've added a test method, that waits whole four seconds. Therefore I can say, that the execution is in fact simultaneously.

Comment: By removing every async/await at once you lost all traces of the original source of the problem. Now neither you, nor any of us, learned something useful from all of this. Maybe you learned that async/await is difficult, and you should avoid it. Which is a sad lesson to learn, because async/await is a really useful tool. A tool that once you conquer it, you can no longer live without it.

Comment: I don't think async/await is bad. And it will eventually get back to me, but in a different place. For this specific problem I found a solution, because of EVERYONE who helped. Don't worry, there are plenty of questions that I will have to face related to async/await ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm facing the original problem again, that SomeMethod3 is executed before ExecuteParallelAsync is finished

Then this is not a use case for asynchronous programming. Your requirement is that this is synchronous.

That is especially so since you said that `MyMethod1`/`MyMethod2`/`MyMethod3` are not asynchronous methods. If they were, that would be a [totally different thing](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/34233). But since they aren't, I don't see any value in trying to use `async` and `await` here.

But don't confuse asynchronous with parallel. It seems you want the methods called in `ExecuteParallelAsync` to be run in parallel, that's fine. You just don't need `async` and `await`.

For example:

```cs
private void ExecuteSequential()
{
    List<Action> sequentialMethods = new List<Action>()
    {
        SomeMethod1,
        SomeMethod2,
        ExecuteParallel,
        SomeMethod3,
        SomeMethod4
    };

    for ( int i = 0 ; i < sequentialMethods.Count ; i++ )
    {
        sequentialMethods.ElementAt( i ).Invoke();
    }
}

private void ExecuteParallel()
{
    List<Action> methods = new List<Action>()
    {
        MyMethod1,
        MyMethod2,
        MyMethod3
    };

    Parallel.ForEach( methods , ( currentMethod ) => currentMethod.Invoke() );            
}
```

Comment: Thanks you very much Gabriel. I found my mistake. I'm going to edit the original post and post the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an `Action` that when invoked will start the task and wait for it to complete, like this:

```
List<Action> sequentialMethods = new List<Action>()
{
    SomeMethod1,
    SomeMethod2,
    () => ExecuteParallelAsync().Wait(),
    SomeMethod3,
    SomeMethod4
};
```

Comment: Thanks Theodor, but nothing changes. Is my approach wrong entirely?

Comment: The methods are invoked in this order: SomeMethod1, then SomeMethod2, then (in parallel: SomeMethod1 and SomeMethod2 and SomeMethod3), then SomeMethod3, and then finally SomeMethod4. Isn't this what you want? If you don't want the SomeMethod1, SomeMethod2 and SomeMethod3 to be invoked twice, just remove them from the list.

Comment: It's exactly what I want. However, in the real application the methods are invoked in this order: SomeMethod1, SomeMethod2, first method in ExecuteParallelAsync, SomeMethod3, SomeMethod 4, SecondMethod from ExecuteParallelAsync, some methods in the application, third method from ExecuteParralelAsync, and so on. So the key is, ExecuteParallelAsync has to be finished before SomeMethod3 is executed, because if not the application crashes later on. Is everything executed sequentially, the application is getting slow.

Comment: I strongly suspect that `MyMethod1`, `MyMethod2` and `MyMethod3` are `async void` methods.

Comment: No, they aren't. They are plain *protected virtual void* in the base class and therefore *protected override void* in the derived class. The only two methods that I have changed are ExecuteSequential and ExecuteParallelAsync from *void* to *async Task*.

Comment: Somewhere in your code base must be fired-end-forgotten tasks. Make a search for `Task.Run` and confirm that all tasks are awaited. Make also a search for `async void`, in case you forgot to fix something.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a version:

```
private async Task  ExecuteSequential()
{
    var sequentialMethods = new List<Func<Task>>()
    {
        () => Task.Run(SomeMethod1),
        () => Task.Run(() => SomeMethod2("Hey!")), 
        ExecuteParallelAsync, 
        () => Task.Run(SomeMethod3),
        () => Task.Run(SomeMethod4)
    };

    for ( int i = 0 ; i < sequentialMethods.Count ; i++ )
    {
        Task t = sequentialMethods[i].Invoke(); 
        await t;
        // or just await sequentialMethods[i]();
    }
}
```

---

Just for the record, `ExecuteSequential` could just be a standard async method (which are very good in executing things sequentially).

```
private async Task ExecuteSequential()
{
  SomeMethod1();
  SomeMethod2();
  await ExecuteParallelAsync(); 
  SomeMethod3();
  SomeMethod4();
};
```

---

## Edit: Test

### Code

```
class Program
{
    public void MyMethod1() => Console.WriteLine("||My1");
    public void MyMethod2() => Console.WriteLine("||My2");
    public void MyMethod3() => Console.WriteLine("||My3");

    private async Task ExecuteParallelAsync()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("||Start");
        List<Action> methods = new List<Action>() { MyMethod1, MyMethod2, MyMethod3 };

        await Task.Run(() => { Parallel.ForEach(methods, 
           (currentMethod) => currentMethod.Invoke()); }); // This could be just 'currentMethod();' (no Invoke())
        Console.WriteLine("||End");
    }


    public void SomeMethod1() => Console.WriteLine("Some1");
    public void SomeMethod2(string s) => Console.WriteLine($"Some2: {s}");
    public void SomeMethod3() => Console.WriteLine("Some3");
    public void SomeMethod4() => Console.WriteLine("Some4");

    private async Task ExecuteSequential()
    {
        var sequentialMethods = new List<Func<Task>>()
        {
           () => Task.Run(SomeMethod1),
           () => Task.Run(() => SomeMethod2("Hey!")),
           ExecuteParallelAsync,
           () => Task.Run(SomeMethod3),
           () => Task.Run(SomeMethod4)
        };

        for (int i = 0; i < sequentialMethods.Count; i++)
        {
            await sequentialMethods[i]();
        }
    }

    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        await new Program().ExecuteSequential();
        Console.WriteLine("All done");
    }
}
```

### Output

```
Some1
Some2: Hey!
||Start
||My3
||My2
||My1
||End
Some3
Some4
All done
```

`My1`, `My2`, and `My3` will change order between executions, but always within `||Start` and `||End`.

Comment: Thank you very much for this new approach. Unfortunately, it doesn't change anything. (Refers to your answer before the edit)

Comment: What do you mean by 'Unfortunately, it doesn't change anything.'? Both approaches will result in sequential execution.

Comment: I added a test.

Comment: Thank you very much @tymtam for all your efforts, I really do appreciate it. I've copied your test setup and it works absolutely correct. In my real application however, it doesn't work. So I guess, the simultaneous execution isn't the issue. But what could it be?