# Async method is not executed in the right (expected) order

Tags: c#, async-await, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I have a component with the following event:

```
    // MyComponent :
    [Parameter] public EventCallback<DataChangedEventArgs> OnTextChanged { get; set; }

    protected async void SomeMethod(ChangeEventArgs args)
    {
        DataChangedEventArgs evArg =new DataChangedEventArgs(args.value);
        Console.Writeline("1");
        await OnTextChanged.InvokeAsync(evArg);
        Items = evArg.Data; // <=== problem here: Data is always null.
        Console.Writeline("4");
    }
```

When I use and handle the `OnTextChanged` event on another component, I set the `Data` property of `DataChangedEventArgs`:

```
 // AnotherComponent that uses MyComponent:
 public async void theTextChanged(DataChangedEventArgs args)
 {
      //...
      Console.Writeline("2");
      args.Data = await GetAPersonAsync(); // or some other object
      Console.Writeline("3");
 }
```

Now I expect `Items` to be set to the `Person` (the line `Items = evArg.Data`). But `Data` is always null, which means the changes that have been made to `args.Data`(which is a reference type) in event handler are not accessible in the invoking method the `SomeMethod`.

Can anyone help me with that ?

**UPDATE:** I think it has something to do with `async` method, as the console result is not as I expect (1,2,3,4):

```
console:
1
2
4
3
```

Comment: Try using async Task instead of async void

Comment: @MisterMagoo that worked! thank you. Please answer the question so I can  mark it as asnwer. I also change to title to more proper one

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# async/await await doesn't await](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58431968/c-sharp-async-await-await-doesnt-await)

Comment: What does `OnTextChanged` look like?

Comment: Adding on to what @MisterMagoo suggested, you should avoid using `async void` because the problem with calling `async void` is that you don’t even get the task back. You have no way of knowing when the function’s task has completed. And that makes debugging 10x harder.

Comment: [Avoid async void](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming#avoid-async-void).

Comment: @GSerg yes but people may search in different ways, I think my title is more clear that than the one you suggested.

Comment: @nAviD Not sure I get you. If you are complaining at the close vote but admitting it answers your question, then just press the big blue button. I [did not](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/265737/11683) suggest that you delete your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use async Task instead of async void.

Theodor provided a [link to the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming#avoid-async-void)

Answer (score 2):

To add some meat to @Mister Magoo's answer, I believe the Blazor code for the event handlers looks something like this (simplified for clarity):

```cs
var task = InvokeAsync(EventMethod);
StateHasChanged();
if (task.Status != TaskStatus.RanToCompletion && task.Status != TaskStatus.Canceled)
{
    await task;
    StateHasChanged();
}
```

If your `EventMethod` returns a void, `InvokeAsync` returns a completed `Task` as soon as `EventMethod` yields.  Only one `StateHasChanged` gets called - the `if` block is skipped.  Anything that happens in `EventMethod` after the yield is not reflected in the UI until another component UI update occurs.