# How does async methods with for loops work in C#?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I have a code in C# like this:

```
FirstMethod();
Console.WriteLine("OK");
Console.ReadKey();

static async void FirstMethod()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        await FileLengthAwaiter(i);
}

static async Task FileLengthAwaiter(int i)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"start method {i}");
    await Task.Delay(1000);
    Console.WriteLine($"end method {i}");
}
```

When I run this code, in the first iteration of the for loop, when i equals to 0, by running the await statement, the method 'FirstMethod' will return and the "OK" will be printed by the Console statement.
But for the remained iterations of the for loop, when running the await statement, it returns the method 'FirstMethod', but it doesn't print the "OK".
Why does this happen? I expect the code to run the Consule statement and prints "OK" for each iteration of the for loop. But it doesn't happen.
Could anyone help me?
The output is like this:

```
start method 0
OK
end method 0
start method 1
end method 1
start method 2
end method 2
start method 3
end method 3
start method 4
end method 4
start method 5
end method 5
start method 6
end method 6
start method 7
end method 7
start method 8
end method 8
start method 9
end method 9
```

Comment: Why would you expect "OK" to be printed in a loop when the line of code which prints it is not in a loop?  It sounds like the code is working exactly as written, but you just have an invalid expectation.  Have you tried moving that line of code to be in the loop within the function?

Comment: The code works exactly as I would expect it. There is exactly one statement of `Console.WriteLine("OK");` in your code. Or did you want to put it into your loop?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# async/await await doesn't await](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58431968/c-sharp-async-await-await-doesnt-await)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> FirstMethod();

This will run the code in the method until it gets to the first await, i.e. when it gets to `Task.Delay(1000)`, so it will print `"start method 0"`. Since `FirstMethod()` is not awaited, the main thread will then continue to run the rest of the code. I.e.

```
Console.WriteLine("OK");
Console.ReadKey();
```

The main thread will then get stuck inside `ReadKey`. After 1000ms has elapsed the `Task.Delay` will complete, and the execution will continue where it left of, on a thread pool thread, and print "end method 0". It will then continue until it gets to the next `Task.Delay`. At that point the threadpool thread will just be returned back to the pool until the task completes.

After the loop eventually completes nothing more will happen, and since `FirstMethod()` does not return any task there will be no way to check if the method actually reached the end of the loop or somehow failed. This is sometimes called "fire and forget", and should be avoided outside of button event handlers or similar.

Since the `Console.WriteLine("OK")` is not inside the loop it should not print more than once.

If you want to read more about how async await is implemented I would recommend reading [Dissecting the async methods in C#](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/dissecting-the-async-methods-in-c/)